# Why does the fpga run though the entire 32bit counter sequence quickly but when running it test on the computer it took a long time

Tags: fpga

Why does the fpga run though the entire 32bit counter sequence quickly but when running it test on the computer it took a long time??

Comment: Because purple strawberry Thursdays.

Comment: Why do cheetahs run faster than humans? They're completely different animals.

Answer (score 6):

Software simulations run slower than the hardware does. It's just a fact of life. In exchange, you get incredible visibility into the details of the logic for debugging.

For example, on the moderate-complexity designs that I've done recently, I find that the simulation runs about 1/1000 as fast as the hardware — in other words, it takes 1 second to simulate 1 ms of time on the FGPA. Instead of processing video at 60 fps, I get about 4 fpm (frames per minute). I can live with that.